# Join same table on different conditions

Tags: sql, linq

I have 3 tables.

- User (Fields: User Id and name )
- MonthsMap (Fields: UserId, Month, orderId)
- OrderTable (Fields: OrderId, Order Quntity, etc)

My requirement is like this:

If user's has orders for Novemeber, show Novemeber orders, else show October month's orders.

Currently what I am doing is

```
foreach(user)
{
    join User table with MonthsMap table where month = november
    if( result is null )
    {
        join User table with MonthsMap table where month = october join order table to get October order details
    }
    else
    {
        join User table with MonthsMap table where month = november join order table to get november order details
    }
}
```

It takes lot of time as for loop in used for iterating each user. I am using Linq to SQL and is there any better Linq option I can use to get all user;s order in single query.

Thanks for all your answers, but sorry that my example made you little confused. The exact scenario is like this, user can have different type of orders( eg:- normal orders and urgent orders ).  So now instead of months_map table i will use a order map table( fields user Id, order_type("normal/urgent/very urgent"), order_id)

So my application has to list orders of all users in user tables.

Listing should be such that

- if user has a very urgent orders, application has to show his very urgent orders only
- else if user has a urgent orders, application has to show his urgent orders only
- else if user has normal orders, application has to show his normal order only
- else just show the user names, order details left blank.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need last/previous months at common, not exactly october/november. If so then use the following algorithm:
Select * from inner join of Users/MonthMap/OrdersTable where OrderTable.MonthNo = max of OrderTable.MonthNo for the current user.

```
var result =
    from u in users
    join mm in mms on u.UserId equals mm.UserId
    join ot in ots on mm.OrderId equals ot.OrderId
    where mm.MonthNo == (
                            from mm1 in mms
                            where mm1.UserId == u.UserId
                            select mm1.MonthNo
                        ).Max()
    select new {u, mm, ot};
```

Comment: Perhaps I missed something... Where's the "MonthNo" field in the "OrderTable"?

Comment: This should work. Notice, i use inner join (this will not give rows for users that doesnt have at least one monthmap with matching order).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd write the query in SQL and would approach the problem something like this:

```
SELECT user.userid
     , user.name
     , october_orders.orderquantity
     , november_orders.orderquantity
     , Coalesce(october_orders.orderquantity, november_orders.orderquantity)
FROM   user
 LEFT
  JOIN monthsmap
    ON monthsmap.userid = user.userid
 LEFT
  JOIN ordertable As october_orders
    ON october_orders.orderid = monthsmap.orderid
   AND monthsmap.month = 'october'
 LEFT
  JOIN ordertable As november_orders
    ON november_orders.orderid = monthsmap.orderid
   AND monthsmap.month = 'november'
```

Have a play and see how you get on.

Comment: if you edit
`, october_orders.orderquantity`
`, november_orders.orderquantity`
into something like
`nvl(november_orders.orderquantity, october_orders.orderquantity)`
you can get the "If user's has orders for Novemeber, show Novemeber orders, else show October month's orders" as well. however i suspect a more general approach can be made that will not limit the query to october and november

Comment: @BrettSchneider I used the `Coalesce()` function to do that already ;) On the ability to make the approach more generic (this month vs last month) I would absolutely agree that it will be the next thing to do, however the Asker has not provided enough detail in their post without making some wild assumptions e.g. we don't know the data type of "month" and there is no apparent "year" portion to play with.

Comment: @BrettSchneider apologies if that last response sounds defensive, it's not meant in such a way! :)

Comment: oops sorry, that's my bad. i did not notice that line. please ignore my comment. you are right, there is insufficient context to provide a more general approach. also having months as text rather than numbers will make this endeavor more complex than necessary. probably monthsmap has more columns to offer

Answer (score 0):

try this sql

```
select ot.*
  from OrderTable ot, MonthsMap mm
 where ot.orderid = mm.orderid
   and mm.userid = :userid
   and mm.month = case
           when (select count(*)
                   from MonthsMap mm1
                  where mm1.userid = mm.userid
                    and mm1.month = 'november') > 0 then
            'november'
           else
            'october'
       end;
```